# Saving numbers as a string in a csv

Tags: php, csv

I am trying to put a column with a number with leading zeros into a csv file, but it keeps truncating the leading zeros, what can I do to keep them?

Here is the code I am using:

```
// fopen() here
function clean_zip($string){
    if(preg_match("/^\d{5,}/", $string)){
        $string = str_pad($string, 5, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
    }
    return $string;
}

while(($csv = fgetcsv($rhandle)) !== false){
    // other rows here
    $fcsv[9]  = (string)clean_zip($csv[9]);
    fputcsv($whandle, $fcsv);
}
```

Comment: Are you looking at the raw output file in a text editor, or are you opening it in a spreadsheet editor like Excel?

Comment: I was opening in excel, but I got it! It was trying to force the column to an int because it thought that, that would be best, but if I tell Libre Office to display the column as text it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just needed to tell Libre Office to display the column as a Text column instead of What ever it thought would be best for the column/cell.

Comment: Ayep. Just in case someone else has the same issue with Excel, if you simply open the .csv file it doesn't seem to want to display right no matter what you set the formatting to. Open a new file, then go to Data > Import From Text > yadda yadda yadda > while you're still in the wizard set the 'Column Data Format' to Text and you'll get your leading zeroes.

Answer (score 3):

As already pointed out in the comments, wrapping a number with double quotes (`"`) will result in something like `"0123"`.

The way to go is adding a leading single quote (`'`) as written down in the documentation:

> If you decide to enter a number directly as text, enter an apostrophe
>   (`'`) first. For example, for years in column headings, you can enter
>   '1999, '2000 and '2001. The apostrophe is not visible in the cell, it
>   only indicates that the entry is to be recognized as a text. This is
>   useful if, for example, you enter a telephone number or postal code
>   that begins with a zero (0), because a zero (0) at the start of a
>   sequence of digits is removed in normal number formats.
>
> *Source: [Formatting Numbers as Text](https://help.libreoffice.org/Calc/Formatting_Numbers_as_Text)*

The data is now parsed as a string, which results in it being ignored in a function.

Another way is to format the column as a text column.

Answer (score -1):

Wrap with double quote characters (").  This is easy enough if you're sure there are only numbers -- if there's a possibility of having quotes in the string you'll have to be more careful.

Comment: If I wrap it in quotes, it then puts quotes around it: `""0123""` then displays like this in excel: `"0123"`